# How to avoid using implementation types for HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Earlier it was

```
 public static final Map<BigInteger, String> CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST = new HashMap<BigInteger, String>()
```

After changing

```
public static final Map<BigInteger, String> CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST = new HashMap<BigInteger, String>(){{
    put(Constants.STATUS_CANCELLED, "Cancelled");
    put(Constants.STATUS_TERMINATED, "Terminated");
}};
```

Getting Error message:

```
Class definition changed (and this is unsupported)
Added elements: public static final java.util.Map com.Constants.CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST
Removed elements: public static final java.util.HashMap com.Constants.CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)
```

Comment: Offtopic: You don't want to use `BigInteger` for any kind of enumerated keys. These objects are huge, when all you want is a value unique among the maybe dozen or even thousand key instances in your Constants class. Prefer `int`/`Integer` or an enum or something like that.

Comment: @ hiergiltdiestfu:Actually as u told the scenario is for unique among the maybe dozen or even thousand objects .So i prefer using BigInteger rather than Integer/int .Is there a way out for this problem

Comment: Why? Are you likely to exceed 2E32 elements?

Comment: @ hiergiltdiestfu:public static final BigInteger STATUS_CANCELLED = BigInteger.valueOf(9134254847713154879L);
 public static final BigInteger STATUS_TERMINATED = BigInteger.valueOf(9134254847713154885L); The ids are like this

Comment: Are these high numbers imposed on you from the outside? In any case, these still do fit inside a `long`/`Long` (up to ca. +9,223*10^18). I just wanted to highlight that a `BigInteger` is approximately as heavy as about 10 Integers, and often used in uncalled for places.

Comment: A benchmark, of which the results have been recorded in my answer, shows that the penalty for using BigInteger over Integer is not factor 10, but rather factor 3. In so far, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to put some kind of default values into that static map.

This should be done in a separate static initializer block, placed after the field initialization:

```
public static final Map<BigInteger, String> CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST = new HashMap<BigInteger, String>();

static {
    CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST.put(Constants.STATUS_CANCELLED, "Cancelled");
    CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST.put(Constants.STATUS_TERMINATED, "Terminated");
};
```

And as an aside: You very probably don't want to use `BigInteger` for any kind of enumerated keys. These objects are huge, when all you want is a value unique among the maybe dozen or even thousand key instances in your `Constants` class. Prefer `int`/`Integer` or an `enum` or something like that.

EDIT: The aside about the footprint of a `BigInteger` is based on jdk7 and has been challenged in the comments. I did a simple benchmark for integer-range values in jdk8u45 and found a factor of 3 for the footprint Integer vs. BigInteger , which is admittedly not "huge" anymore. Nonetheless, in my opinion, BigInteger should only be used when arithmetics on big numbers is needed. Instead I'd always try to use simple types, including String (which for the range tested in the benchmark on average still used eight Bytes less than BigInteger). (Averages for the range [0,100k[, Integer~15B, Long~30B, String~40B, BigInteger~48B)

Comment: Actually there is no reason why a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) should be huge. The data stored expands to meet the requirements of the number to be stored using an `int[]` but if the number can fit an `int` then the array is not allocated.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon you are right, it might expand the actual value field as needed, but as of jdk8u45, each BigInteger class still contains a couple additional int fields for caching meta data about the value. I admit the last time I took a look at the memory footprint was probably in some jdk7, but back then I remember counting about 10 relevant int attributes per BigInteger, regardless of the represented value.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon did a quick benchmark (using `Runtime#freeMemory()`) on 8u45: allocating 100k Ints, Longs and BigIntegers in the int-Range provides these numbers: an Integer takes about 17 Bytes, a Long 30B and a BigInteger occupies about 48 Bytes. That's not as impressive as it used to be, but for stuff that can be expressed as an Integer and doesn't need the Big Number arithmetics, it's still factor 3.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine:

```
public class Test {
    public static final Map<BigInteger, String> CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST = new HashMap<BigInteger, String>(){{
        put(BigInteger.ONE, "Cancelled");
        put(BigInteger.ZERO, "Terminated");
    }};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CONTRACT_STATUS_LIST.toString());
    }
}
```